# How to let my HTML input be used by my JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, input, output

So I have set up many objects with my JavaScript, a HTML dropdown list so you can select which pokemon

As you can see I have tried to access the 'bulbasaur' object by using document.getElementById on a list which has a dropdown value of 'bulbasaur'. When I do console.log(mon) it prints 'bulbasaur' so I'm guessing I just can't access the object this way. Is there a  workaround? Thanks

```js
const base =10;
class Pokemon {
  constructor(name, shinyrate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.shinyrate = shinyrate;
  }
}
const bulbasaur = new Pokemon('Bulbasaur', base);

function shundoWild() {
  let mon = document.getElementById("list").value;
  let nowb = mon.shinyrate * ivCombinations(ivFloor.wild);
  let wb = mon.shinyrate * ivCombinations(ivFloor.weatherBoost);
  document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = ("The chance to get a SHUNDO " + mon.name + " wild catch is ~1/" + wb + " when weather boosted, or ~1/" + nowb + " when not weather boosted.")
}
```

```html
<select id="list" onchange="shundoWild();">
  <option value="bulbasaur">Bulbasaur</option>
  <option value="ekans">Ekans</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update with relevant code to a [mcve] - we need ivCombinations,  ivFloor, wilde etc

Comment: Also you need a "Please select" or the user cannot select a bulbasaur without first selecting Ekans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making `bulbasaur` and `ekans` variables, make them properties of an object:

```js
const characters = {
  bulbasaur: new Pokemon('Bulbasaur', base),
  ekans: new Pokemon('Ekans', base)
}
```

The you can access them by name:

```js
  let name = document.getElementById("list").value;
  const mon = characters[name];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate your Pokemon into an Object structure and access it as so:

```js
const base =10;
class Pokemon {
  constructor(name, shinyrate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.shinyrate = shinyrate;
  }
}
const pokemon = {
    "bulbasaur": new Pokemon('Bulbasaur', base)
};

function shundoWild() {
  let mon = pokemon[document.getElementById("list").value];
  let nowb = mon.shinyrate * ivCombinations(ivFloor.wild);
  let wb = mon.shinyrate * ivCombinations(ivFloor.weatherBoost);
  document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = ("The chance to get a SHUNDO " + mon.name + " wild catch is ~1/" + wb + " when weather boosted, or ~1/" + nowb + " when not weather boosted.")
}
```

```html
<select id="list" onchange="shundoWild();">
  <option value="bulbasaur">Bulbasaur</option>
  <option value="ekans">Ekans</option>
</select>
```